# R Interclass distance matrix

Tags: r, distance-matrix

This question is sort of a follow-up to [how to extract intragroup and intergroup distances from a distance matrix? in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367277/how-to-extract-intragroup-and-intergroup-distances-from-a-distance-matrix-in-r). In that question, they first computed the distance matrix for all points, and then simply extracted the inter-class distance matrix. I have a situation where I'd like to bypass the initial computation and skip right to extraction, i.e. I want to directly compute the inter-class distance matrix. Drawing from the linked example, with tweaks, let's say I have some data in a dataframe called `df`:

```
values<-c(0.002,0.3,0.4,0.005,0.6,0.2,0.001,0.002,0.3,0.01)
class<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","B","A")
df<-data.frame(values, class)
```

What I'd like is a distance matrix:

```
    1    2    3    8   10
4 .003 .295 .395 .003 .005
5 .598 .300 .200 .598 .590
6 .198 .100 .200 .198 .190
7 .001 .299 .399 .001 .009
9 .298 .000 .100 .298 .290
```

Does there already exist in R an elegant and fast way to do this?

**EDIT** After receiving a good solution for the 1D case above, I thought of a bonus question: what about a higher-dimensional case, say if instead `df` looks like this:

```
values1<-c(0.002,0.3,0.4,0.005,0.6,0.2,0.001,0.002,0.3,0.01)
values2<-c(0.001,0.1,0.1,0.001,0.1,0.1,0.001,0.001,0.1,0.01)
class<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","B","A")
df<-data.frame(values1, values2, class)
```

And I'm interested in again getting a matrix of the Euclidean distance between points in class `B` with points in class `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general `n`-dimensional Euclidean distance, we can exploit the equation (not R, but algebra):

```
square_dist(b,a) = sum_i(b[i]*b[i]) + sum_i(a[i]*a[i]) - 2*inner_prod(b,a)
```

where the sums are over the dimensions of vectors `a` and `b` for `i=[1,n]`. Here, `a` and `b` are one pair from `A` and `B`. The key here is that this equation can be written as a matrix equation for all pairs in `A` and `B`.

In code:

```
## First split the data with respect to the class
n <- 2   ## the number of dimensions, for this example is 2
tmp <- split(df[,1:n], df$class)

d <- sqrt(matrix(rowSums(expand.grid(rowSums(tmp$B*tmp$B),rowSums(tmp$A*tmp$A))),
                 nrow=nrow(tmp$B)) - 
          2. * as.matrix(tmp$B) %*% t(as.matrix(tmp$A)))
```

Notes:

1. The inner `rowSums` compute `sum_i(b[i]*b[i])` and `sum_i(a[i]*a[i])` for each `b` in `B` and `a` in `A`, respectively.
2. `expand.grid` then generates all pairs between `B` and `A`.
3. The outer `rowSums` computes the `sum_i(b[i]*b[i]) + sum_i(a[i]*a[i])` for all these pairs.
4. This result is then reshaped into a `matrix`. Note that the number of rows of this matrix is the number of points of class `B` as you requested.
5. Then subtract two times the inner product of all pairs. This inner product can be written as a matrix multiply `tmp$B %*% t(tmp$A)` where I left out the coercion to matrix for clarity.
6. Finally, take the square root.

Using this code with your data:

```
print(d)
##          1         2         3         8         10
##4 0.0030000 0.3111688 0.4072174 0.0030000 0.01029563
##5 0.6061394 0.3000000 0.2000000 0.6061394 0.59682493
##6 0.2213707 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.2213707 0.21023796
##7 0.0010000 0.3149635 0.4110985 0.0010000 0.01272792
##9 0.3140143 0.0000000 0.1000000 0.3140143 0.30364453
```

Note that this code will work for any `n > 1`. We can recover your previous 1-d result by setting `n` to `1` and not perform the inner `rowSums` (because there is now only one column in `tmp$A` and `tmp$B`):

```
n <- 1   ## the number of dimensions, set this now to 1
tmp <- split(df[,1:n], df$class)

d <- sqrt(matrix(rowSums(expand.grid(tmp$B*tmp$B,tmp$A*tmp$A)),
                 nrow=length(tmp$B)) - 
          2. * as.matrix(tmp$B) %*% t(as.matrix(tmp$A)))
print(d)
##      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
##[1,] 0.003 0.295 0.395 0.003 0.005
##[2,] 0.598 0.300 0.200 0.598 0.590
##[3,] 0.198 0.100 0.200 0.198 0.190
##[4,] 0.001 0.299 0.399 0.001 0.009
##[5,] 0.298 0.000 0.100 0.298 0.290
```

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly detailed response! This works perfectly.

Comment: This works, but I'm finding a problem: with a much larger dataset of 1000 points in each class, I'm getting NaN's in `d`. I'm checking the entries of `tmp$A` and `tmp$B` using `a <- which(is.nan(d), arr.ind=T)`, and then doing, for instance `tmp$A[a[1],]` and `tmp$A[a[nrow(a) + 1],]` and I find that the NaN's seem to occur when the vectors from both classes are identical. Is this a precision thing? Sorry I can't provide a concrete example since my dataset is too big.

Comment: It could be. The only cause for NaNs in the computation is if the square distance turns out to be negative, which can be due to precision. To check, remove the square root and see if the resulting matrix have negative numbers. These should be small. If that is the problem, then simply threshold to zero before taking the square root. If that is not the problem, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt via generating each combination and then simply taking the difference from each value:

```
abs(matrix(Reduce(`-`, expand.grid(split(df$values, df$class))), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,] 0.003 0.295 0.395 0.003 0.005
#[2,] 0.598 0.300 0.200 0.598 0.590
#[3,] 0.198 0.100 0.200 0.198 0.190
#[4,] 0.001 0.299 0.399 0.001 0.009
#[5,] 0.298 0.000 0.100 0.298 0.290
```

Comment: This is perfect! A simple question: what are the possible types of functions that Reduce() can take? For instance, is it possible to take an n-dimensional Euclidian distance, not just 1-D distance (and here that's kind of hacked by taking the absolute value of an absolute difference), in the example above there's only one column of values, but what if I were to have three different values columns, say `value1`, `value2` and `value3`?

Comment: @itf - I don't think this is really extensible to >1D distances unfortunately. I'd have to give it a lot more thought.

Comment: No problem, it's my fault for not having posted a question about higher-dimensional distance. I'll edit my question accordingly, and see if more solutions come up. Thanks for your 1D solution!